# Double variable integration unable to prove that integration limits are real

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages, assumptions

I have simple question regarding double integrating a function.

`J*Integrate[Integrate[Cos[ArcTan[Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2]/L]], {b, -b, b}], {a, -a,a}]`

The error message: "Unable to prove that integration limits {-a,a} are real. Adding 
assumptions may help" appears.

I tried adding assumptions:

`J*Integrate[Integrate[Cos[ArcTan[Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2]/L]], {b, -b, b}, Assumptions -> {Re[x], Re[y], Re[a] > 0, Re[b] > 0}], {a, -a, a}, Assumptions -> {Re[x], Re[y], Re[a] > 0, Re[b] > 0}]`

But this did not seem to help, the same error message appears. I tried a few different combination of assumptions but nothing seems to work.

Any help?

Comment: `Re[x]` calculates the real part of `x`; it does not indicate that $x$ is real. For that you should use `Element[x, Reals]`. See [`Element`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html).

Comment: I tried this, but still get the same error...